# Fill up JavaFX buttons with arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx

in a project i'm making, I'm trying to fill up my JavaFX buttons with an arraylist.

Below you find my view class where I make 7 buttons. Now in my Model class I read in a file where I split the countries and continents in two seperate arraylists. The arraylist "continents" is now filled with 7 continents. Now I want to fill up every button with a continent.

The problem is that the button can only be filled with a String where my getter returns a .

is there a solution so I can transform the arraylist into seperate strings which I can pass on to the buttons?

```
public class GameView extends BorderPane {
private Model model;
private Button[] statement = new Button[7];
private Label lbl;

public GameView() {
    this.initialiseNodes();
    this.layoutNodes();
}

private void initialiseNodes() {
    this.model = new Model();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        this.statement[i] = new Button(model.getContinents());
    }
    this.lbl = new Label("unfinished businness");
}

private void layoutNodes() {
    this.setBottom(lbl);
    BorderPane.setAlignment(lbl,Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
    BorderPane.setMargin(lbl,new Insets(20));

    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(20));
    vbox.setSpacing(10);
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(statement);
    this.setCenter(vbox);
}
}
```

---

---

```
public class Model {
private List<String> countries = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> continents = new ArrayList<>();

public void readFile() throws IOException {
    String[] ss = new String[15];

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/game.txt"))) {
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.replaceAll("\t","\n");
            ss = line.split("\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < ss.length ; i++) {
                if((i%2)==0){
                    countries.add(ss[i]);
                } else{
                    continents.add(ss[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("No file");
    }
}


public List<String> getCountries() {
    return this.countries;
}

public List<String> getContinents() {
    return this.continents;
}
}
```

Comment: You are allowing any number of continents but only 7 buttons. What text should each button have out of all the continents?

Answer (score 0):

Using this:

```
this.statement[i] = new Button(model.getContinents());
```

you are referencing the whole list and not just one contintent.

So what you might want to do instead, is something like this:

```
// At the top, instead of the Button array
final List<Button> statement = new ArrayList<>();

// instead of your for loop
continents
        // Creates a stream of all the continents
        .stream()
        // Creates a new stream of the existing stream that has a maximum amount of 7 items
        .limit(7)
        // Adds a button for every continent in the stream
        .forEach(continent -> statement.add(new Button(continent)));
```